# {N} 6.0 migration: Error: Failed to load component from module:

Tags: nativescript

I’m upgrading my project to {N} 6.0 and hit an error I’m stuck on.  Whenever my app displays a map page I get system errors:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onClick failed
System.err: Error: Failed to load component from module: ./views/map-page/
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'loadInternal', file:'file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js:82:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js:62:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js.FrameBase.navigate', file:'file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js:129:0
```

So, this error occurs while the app is navigating to the map page, but the page’s .js file never receives control.  I thought the problem might be that the google-maps-sdk uses a namespace definition,

```
<Page 
  xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
  xmlns:maps="nativescript-google-maps-sdk" 
  navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" navigatingFrom="onNavigatingFrom" loaded="onLoaded" class="page”>
```

But I have other pages with namespaces (sidedrawer) and they work OK.  I’ve read through the {N} 6.0 migration docs and I can’t find anything that seems to match.  At this point I’ve run out of ideas to pursue.

Comment: Can you share the playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this was subtle... after further debugging and comparing to code that worked, this was the code in error:

```
// Navigate to map-page to show selected map
  var navigationOptions = {
    moduleName: "./views/map-page/",
    context: { bindingContext: viewModel }
  }
  frame.topmost().navigate(navigationOptions);
```

The problem was the trailing slash on the moduleName. Once I removed that, the map page worked as expected, just as it had in {N} 3, 4, and 5.

Oh well, at least it's working!